# In regard to short

Tags: word-usage

If I want to express that I am now 40 pcs short of the Item, can I say *there are still 40pcs short*,or *there are 40 pcs shortage*.

Answer (score 1):

Firstlym it sounds confusing to say that we are 40 pieces short of "an item", because "an item" is usually one single thing, so it is not clear how "an item" can be missing 40 pieces.  You might mean something like "40 pieces short of" a *complete set*, or a *full load*, or something else, but it is hard to know exactly what to say without knowing what exactly you are referring to.

You already said the most idiomatic and fluent way: **we are 40 pieces short**.  We normally say that "*we are short* (a thing)", or "*we are (a thing) short*", meaning that we are missing it, not that the thing itself is short.

**there are 40 pieces shortage** doesn't quite make sense.  *Shortage* is a singular, countable noun, so you can't say "There are shortage".  But you could say "There is *a shortage of* 40 pieces" or "There are 40 pieces *missing*".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to express an electronic component, for example, its part number is 123-456, and I need a total of 60 pcs 123-456 to produce an electronic device，but I only have 20 pcs 123-456 on hand.

Comment: As @stangdon pointed out, in that case you would use "we are short," rather than saying that the pieces themselves are short. The way I would word that is "I am short 40 pieces of item number 123-456." You could move the word 'short' after the word 'pieces,' but then it sounds a bit like you need 40 more pieces (of some undefined thing) in order to make item number 123-456.