# In regard to "shortage"

Tags: word-usage

If I want to produce a batch of circuit boards which consist of various electronic components. But I found there is a shortage of a certain component whose part number is xxxx. Can I say
there is a shortage of 44 pcs xxxx, or I should say there are 44 pcs shortage of xxxx.

Comment: This question is almost identical to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158831/in-regard-to-short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given only the choices you mentioned:

> 1. there is a shortage of 44 pcs xxxx.

or

> 2. there are 44 pcs shortage of xxxx.

Then #1 is better. #2 is grammatically incorrect because "shortage" is singular. In that sentence, it appears that "44 pcs" is an adjective modifying "shortage", which still needs to be singular.

The second sentence could be adjusted a bit:

> 3. there is a 44 pcs. shortage of xxxx.

In English you often use the singular of pieces in a plural context:  "A 500 piece puzzle", is a puzzle with 500 pieces. That might argue for pc. instead of pcs. for #3.

The following sentence appears grammatically correct and sounds right:

> 4. There is a shortage of 44 pcs. of xxxx.